# Class property is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#

I created a class call Sales with a Amount get/set:

```
class Sales 
{

 public static string Amount { get; set; }

}
```

Then I called from other class, out of a function scope:

```
class Test
{

  Sales.Amount = "10";

  public static VoidSales() 
  {
   .....
  }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
'Fun.Sales.Amount' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
```

But When I use in a function, it is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean this to be static? I.E there is only one "amount" in your application?

Comment: @Oli - Who cares, this looks terribly like an example (simplified to make some sense, not necessarily logical from a global point of view) and that is a lot better than him dumping 20 pages of code and let us sort out the problem. Let's stick to the question asked.

Comment: @TomTom It makes quite a lot of difference (see my point below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't place these type of assignment statements inside the open class context.  You can only make these type of assignments inside a method.  The only assignments that can be done in the class context are initializations of class level fields.

If this assignment needs to be made when the class is instantiated, then it should be done in the constructor.

Comment: Will to it at the constructor.

Comment: @KelvinFixx Given that the field is static, it should be initialized in the static constructor.  However, it seems very likely that the field should not be static.

Answer (score 2):

I may not be able to explain it well. But a get/set property is actually sort of equivalent to a method. Having said that, I believe you can't call a method outside of a function right?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test
{
  Sales.Amount = "10";
  public static VoidSales() 
  {
   .....
  }
}
```

This is a syntax issue. You can not reference Sales.Amount outside a function - here you define it like a property or variable, and those have to follow the rules of variables (or properties).

You need to create a constructor and move the assignment there. i.e.

```
class Test
{
    Test () {
        Sales.Amount=10;
    }
}
```

The error purely is that the NAME of the item you define (Sales.Amount) is not a valid name in the context of the class outside a function.

}

Answer (score 1):

If it's a static value then it's already been declared elsewhere in your application. You are basically trying to call a method in a place where you can only make assignments.

If this were not a static field then you could make an assignment and then change "Amount" such as

```
class Test 
{ 

  public Sales sales = new Sales()
  {
     Amount = "10" //Assign Value Here
  };

  public Test()  
  { 
     sales.amount = "10"; //Or Assign Value here in constructor
  }  
}
```

If however this is a static field then make the assignment either in the constructor or when you declare the static field.

```
class Sales  
{  
   public static string Amount = "10" //You don't require get/set here  
} 

class Test    
{ 
    public Test()
    {
        Sales.Amount = "10";    
    }
}
```